# Print weekday given a date, issue with scanning in input

Tags: c, date, time

The code i am posting, is a repeated code of my other question that i was able to finally figure out. However, this issue i have is completely different now. The part i am having trouble with is the scanning in the input part.

I have to have 2 valid input formats:

mm/dd/yyyy Example: 03/04/2014

Output: Tuesday

Month dd, yyyy Example: March 04, 2014

Output: Tuesday

The code i have posted actually is able to take in both those formats. However, only the mm/dd/yyyy format prints out the correct weekday. For example, 03/04/2014 prints out a tuesday which is correct. However, when i input March 04, 2014 it prints out a saturday. Im not sure what is wrong...

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int month,day1,day2,totdays,year,dm,dn,leap,rmd;
char month1[10], January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September,    October, November, December;

printf(" ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d",&month,&day1,&year) ||  scanf("%s %d, %d",month1,&day1,&year);



        if(month1==January){
                    month=1;
        }
        if(month1==February){
                    month=2;
                }
        if(month1==March){
                    month=3;
                }
        if(month1==April){
                    month=4;
                }
        if(month1==May){
                    month=5;
                }
        if(month1==June){
                    month=6;
                }
        if(month1==July){
                    month=7;
                }
        if(month1==August){
                    month=8;
                }
        if(month1==September){
                    month=9;
                }
        if(month1==October){
                    month=10;
                }
        if(month1==November){
                    month=11;
                }
        if(month1==December){
                    month=12;
                }






if(((year%4==0) && (year%100!=0)) || (year%400==0))
  {
     if(month==1)
        dm=0;

     if(month==2)
        dm=31;

     if(month==3)
        dm=60;

     if(month==4)
        dm=91;

     if(month==5)
        dm=121;

     if(month==6)
        dm=152;

     if(month==7)
        dm=182;

     if(month==8)
        dm=213;

     if(month==9)
        dm=244;

     if(month==10)
        dm=274;

     if(month==11)
        dm=305;

     if(month==12)
        dm=335;
   }
else
   {
     if(month==1)
        dm=0;

     if(month==2)
        dm=31;

     if(month==3)
        dm=59;

     if(month==4)
        dm=90;

     if(month==5)
        dm=120;

     if(month==6)
        dm=151;

     if(month==7)
        dm=181;

     if(month==8)
        dm=212;

     if(month==9)
        dm=243;

     if(month==10)
        dm=273;

     if(month==11)
        dm=304;

     if(month==12)
        dm=334;
   }


  day2=(year-1905)*(365.25);
  dn=dm+day1;
  totdays=day2+dn;

  rmd=totdays%7;

  if(rmd==2)
    {
       printf("Monday \n");
    }

  if(rmd==3)
    {
       printf("Tuesday \n");
    }

  if(rmd==4)
    {
        printf("Wednesday \n");
    }

  if(rmd==5)
    {
        printf("Thursday \n");
    }

  if(rmd==6)
    {
        printf("Friday \n");
    }

  if(rmd==0)
    {
        printf("Saturday \n");
    }

  if(rmd==1)
    {
        printf("Sunday \n");
    }

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at what your compiler should be telling you:

> warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]

You can't do this as `month1` is a `char*` and `March` is a `char` (named March, and lacking value):

```
if(month1==March) { month=3; }
```

Use the `strcmp` function to compare the strings like this instead:

```
if(strcmp(month1, "March") == 0) { month=3; }
```

Change this in all appropriate places where you test the name of the month, and also you can remove all the variables named after months as you don't need them.

Comment: hmmm, thanks for responding, that method works!.however, im not sure im allowed to use that on this project because i havent even been taught that yet. Would you be able to recommend a better way of taking in the inputs? like as a string or something? something that i may have already learned.

Comment: @user3436065 Why not use the tools the language provide? Your teacher shouldn't complain about that. If you want to accept input in the form of a string like `March 04, 2014` at some point you have to compare the month part of the string to a fixed value, and `strcmp` is the usual way of comparing strings.

Comment: are other ways of comparing a word and a value much more complicated?

Comment: @user3436065 Not really (if you know C well enough), but you would be recreating what strcmp already does (and most likely in a less efficient way).